# How to get form data after action chaining in last action

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Here i am  chaining action then want to get data on last preview action

My First action call `first.jsp`. I Enter some value here I want to get that value on next Action call

```
  <action name="first">
     <result  name="success">/first.jsp</result>
  </action>

  <action name="second" class="com.ved.action.FirstAction">         
      <result name="success">/second.jsp</result>
  </action>

  <action name="preview" class="com.ved.action.SecondAction">
      <result name="success">/preview.jsp</result>
  </action>
```

I want to display first.jsp data on preview.jsp

first.jsp

```
  <s:form action="second">
      <s:textfield name="username" label="UserName"/>
      <s:submit name="next" value="Next"/>
  </s:form>
```

second.jsp

```
   <s:form action="preview">
         <s:textfield  name="address"/>             
   <s:submit name="priview" value="priview"/>
```

preview.jsp

```
  <s:property value="username"/>
  <s:property value="address"/>
```

i want display both page data on preview

my Action is as

```
   public class FirstAction extends ActionSupport{
    private String firstname; 
    public String execute() throws Exception {  
  return SUCCESS;
     }
     //setter getter for firstname
   }

   public class SecondAction extends ActionSupport{
    private String address; 
    public String execute() throws Exception {  
   return SUCCESS;
     }
    //setter getter for address 
    }
```

Comment: Use one action class with different methods: create method for setting `firstName`, `address` and the last method for displaying preview.

Comment: @dave_newton  sir would u like to suggest me...... what should i do....

Comment: @vedprakash you should format your code

Answer (score 1):

**HTTP is stateless.**

Solution:

1) You have to use session to persist the data.

2) During transition from first to second, the data should be in second.jsp. Use html hidden element to store the data of first.jsp. So, you have to restore the data in request scope.

Comment: @ shashi is any alternate to presist that data in session, or hidden field ... i know that ... would u like to share how passs data using pram tag.. can i use here... i have tried it..  <param name="actionName">preview</param>
           <param name="username">${username}</param>
           <param name="lastname">${lastname}</param>
           <param name="city">${city}</param> 
           <param name="state">${state}</param>

Comment: @vedprakash I mention "HTTP is stateless".. Then you need a persistent medium. May be it will be write to an object or write data to database. You can't override the rule of HTTP. Using param tag, you can display the data but you can't used for form submission. You need HTML Input Element or if you wish, you can cleverly append the data in query string of url...